# Get Form Data using Javascript in different file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML file and a JavaScript file  to capture the data,
I had tried to capture the data but it doesn't work, the function is not runs.

Here is my code

**HTML File :**

```
<form class="form-newsletter">
      <div class="form-group">
        <span><input type="text" name="name" value="" class="input-type" placeholder="Masukkan Email Anda"></span>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-yellow" value="SUBMIT" onclick="newsletterFormFunctions()"/>
       </div>
 </form>
```

**JS File:**

```
function newsletterFormFunctions() {
NewsletterConfig.email = '';
NewsletterConfig.name = 'Test';
console.log('Enter Here');

$('form.form-newsletter input[type="submit"]').click(function (evt) {
    validateForm();
});
function validateForm() {
    $('form.form-newsletter input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('form.form-newsletter input[type="submit"]').val('LOADING');
    NewsletterConfig.email = $('form.form-newsletter input.input-type').val();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the event binding outside the 'newsletterFormFunctions' function, say in the document ready event handler.

```js
function newsletterFormFunctions() {
  NewsletterConfig.email = '';
  NewsletterConfig.name = 'Test';
  console.log('Enter Here');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form.form-newsletter input[type="submit"]').click(function(evt) {
    validateForm();
  });

  function validateForm() {
    $('form.form-newsletter input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('form.form-newsletter input[type="submit"]').val('LOADING');
    NewsletterConfig.email = $('form.form-newsletter input.input-type').val();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-newsletter">
  <div class="form-group">
    <span><input type="text" name="name" value="" class="input-type" placeholder="Masukkan Email Anda"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-yellow" value="SUBMIT" onclick="newsletterFormFunctions()" />
  </div>
</form>
```